# Stop timer in the middle of the tick

Tags: c#, timer

I want to stop a timer but in the middle of the tick, before the tick finishes. But when I use a button to stop the timer, it only stops it after the tick finishes all his functions.

I'm using 4 radiobuttons and a timer that keeps changing the selected radiobutton. When I press the Stop button, my timer stops and I need to know what radiobutton is selected, but the timer just stops after the tick finishes, so the selected radiobutton changes.

The code is:

```
namespace teste_bola
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Int32 x = 1000;

        private void ini_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void par_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
        private void t_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 Intervalo = Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text);
            x = Intervalo;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            r3.Select();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
            r2.Select();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
            r1.Select();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
            r2.Select();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
            r3.Select();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
            r4.Select();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you want to make some Knight Rider like effect with variable speed. Maybe think about this (just a suggestion): You could try to only put a single `r#.Select();` action in the timer tick handler, making the timer tick every `x` ms. And then, inside the timer tick handler method, you decide which radio button needs to be `.Select()`ed next, and only select that one. In order to realize that, you obviously need to store the last selected radio button, and the direction the "effect" is currently going (and reverse the direction when it reaches either end).

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a flag `bool shouldStop` , set it when button is clicked, and check it from the `Tick` handler. If it is true, then just exit the method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following what you are trying to accomplish in you code but it seems to me like you are not using the timer correctly.

You should do something like:

On each timer.Tick change the selected radiobox.

What you are actually doing is:

On each timer.Tick change through all radiobox's with a time interval between changes.

This means that on the first timer timeout the tick code is executed.
On the second timer timeout the first tick job was not yet finnished.

This will lead to erratic behaviour to say the least.

My advice. Add the radio buttons to a ArrayList. Then cicle select between each of the ArrayList items on a Timer tick.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        r3.Select();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
        if(timer1.Enabled == false) return;
            r2.Select();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
            if(timer1.Enabled == false) return;
            r1.Select();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
            if(timer1.Enabled == false) return;
            r2.Select();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
            if(timer1.Enabled == false) return;
            r3.Select();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
            if(timer1.Enabled == false) return;
            r4.Select();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can face this behaviour because your thread is sleeping during the execution of the timer1_Tick and thus there might be a queye of events.

As alex proposed you can add a flag, but you should check it after every sleep or, even better, put your animation in the different thread.