# Calling Stop Timer in Timer.Tick

Tags: c#, timer, .net-4.5

I call `myTimer.Stop();` in the middle of the `myTimer_Tick` method. Before asking this question, I read this question: [Stop timer in the middle of the tick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744736/stop-timer-in-the-middle-of-the-tick); but my question is something quit different:

I think if call `myTimer.Stop()` or `myTimer.Enable = false`, the Tick method will run to the end but there won't be the next Tick. In fact, I don't want to stop the Tick method immediately and return.

Am I correct?

edit:
I try to show what I want in an example:

```
void mytimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    someWorks1;
    myTimer.Stop();
    someWorks2;
}
```

I want the `someWorks2` run for the last time too.

Comment: *I don't want to stop the Tick method immediately and return.* Then what do you **want** to do?

Comment: She wants the body of the tick event to execute and then end the timer.

Comment: I want call myTimer.Stop() in the middle of the method's code, but the code run to the end of the Tick method. I want that this be the last Tick of the Timer.

Comment: Add `myTimer.Stop()` at the last line in your method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think if call `myTimer.Stop()` or `myTimer.Enable = false`, the `Tick` method will run to the end but there won't be the next Tick.

Correct. Stopping the timer will *not* kill the thread executing the callback function. Your Tick method will continue to run until it returns.

You can easily code up an example to prove this.